# Informing users of planned downtime on SO

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Can we have the feature informing the SO users of the planned downtime start time and possible duration?.

Comment: I assume you mean for *planned* downtime?

Comment: Right : Updated question for this.

Answer (score 7):

Downtime across the sites is hardly ever that long that you can nick down to the corner store to pick up some supplies.

If things do take a little longer than expected, it will be [posted on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Who's Nick and why is he at the corner store?

Comment: Nick's buying some milk duds and a box of jaffas. He's got a lunch date with Caroline and they're going out to a movie. It's a matinee, `Top Hat.` He was going to buy at the candystand, but this is just a screen in the middle of the park. So that option was out.

Comment: He's still with Caroline? After what she said?